# Pyramid Creation Utility for ArcGIS 10.1 or later

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, envi, image-pyramids

Someone wrote a really neat ENVI Pymramid Creation Utility I am wondering if there is similiar one for ArcGIS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build pyramids in ArcGIS using the built-in tool [Batch Build Pyramids (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000009z000000) or [Build Pyramids (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//0017000000m1000000).

It appears the ArcGIS tools do the same thing as the [ENVI utility](http://www.exelisvis.com/Home/NewsUpdates/TabId/170/ArtMID/735/ArticleID/14124/ENVI-Pyramid-Creation-Utility.aspx), except that ArcGIS stores the pyramid file as a ".ovr" file rather than an ENVI ".enp" file